# Copy-item Files and Folders in Folder of Jenkins server using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I want copy/paste all files and all folder in other path.

May data is:

```
temp
  Deploiement    
    foo.xml
    bar.xml
    Documentation
    brute
```

I read official documentation on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-7.1 and I find this example:

```
Example 3: Copy directory and contents to a new directory
Copy-Item -Path "C:\Logfiles\*" -Destination "C:\Drawings\Logs" -Recurse
```

In my Jenkins, I write this:

```
Copy-Item -Path "temp/Deploiement/*" -Destination "Deploy" -Recurse
```

**Console error:**

```
Copy-Item : Container cannot be copied onto existing leaf item.
At D:\JenkinsWks\workspace\pic\temp\Scripts\packer.ps1:114 char:2
+     Copy-Item -Path "temp/Deploiement/*" -Destination "Deploy" - ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (D:\JenkinsWks\w...t\Documentation:String) [Copy-Item], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CopyContainerItemToLeafError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
 
Copy-Item : Container cannot be copied onto existing leaf item.
At D:\JenkinsWks\workspace\pic\temp\Scripts\packer.ps1:114 char:2
+     Copy-Item -Path "temp/Deploiement/*" -Destination "Deploy" - ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (D:\JenkinsWks\w...nt\brute:String) [Copy-Item], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CopyContainerItemToLeafError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (-Not (Test-Path "Deploy")) {
    md -path "Deploy"
}
Copy-Item -Path "temp/Deploiement/*" -Destination "Deploy" -Recurse
```